# Does statistician Piggy wait longer when she is in a hurry?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, generating-functions

> The statistician Piggy has to wait an amount of time $T_0$ at the post office
>   on an occasion when she is in a great hurry. In order to investigate whether
>   or not chance makes her wait particularly long when she is in a hurry,
>   she checks how many visits she makes to the post office until she has to
>   wait longer than the first time. Formally, let $T_1, T_2, . . . $be the successive
>   waiting times and $N$ be the number of times until some $T_k > T_0$, that is,
>   $${N = k} = {T_j ≤ T_0, 1 ≤ j < k, T_k > T_0}$$
>   What is the distribution of $N$ under the assumption that $(T_n, n ≥ 0)$ are
>   i.i.d. continuous random variables? What can be said about $E(N)$ ?

This question confuses me. Does it have all information needed to solve it? Nothing is said about the distribution of $T_i$. The answer in my book is :
$$P(N=n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ which does not even depend on $T_0$, which as i understand it, is a given time, not a random variable. Where is the trick?

Comment: Well, if we do interpret $T_0$ as a random variable (distributed identically to the other $T_i$), then maybe that is enough to determine the distribution of $N$. For instance, for any specific $T_i$, $P(T_i>T_0)=\frac12$, by symmetry.

Comment: "...under the assumption that $(T_n, {\bf n\ge0})$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables."

Comment: Thanks, ill see what i get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are told the $T_i$ come from a continuous uniform distribution though in fact all that matters is that the distribution is continuous so there are no ties.  To have $n$ be the first time the waiting time exceeds $T_0$ we must have $T_n$ be the greatest waiting time and $T_0$ be the second greatest.  If $T_0$ is not the second greatest we have exceeded it before.  If we draw $n+1$ random numbers, the chance the last one is greatest is $\frac 1{n+1}$.  Given that it is, the chance the first is second largest is $\frac 1n$, so the chance that $n$ is the first time we exceed $T_0$ is $\frac 1{n(n+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

Ross has already given a nice answer; here's another way to look at it:

The probability that $T_0$ is the longest of the $n$ times $T_0$ through $T_{n-1}$ is $\frac1n$. Thus

$$
\mathsf P(N\ge n)=\frac1n\;,
$$

so

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf P(N=n)
&=&
\mathsf P(N\ge n)-\mathsf P(N\ge n+1)
\\
&=&
\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}
\\
&=&
\frac1{n(n+1)}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}